# How do I opt out of emello?

Tags: gmail, trello

I just went upto step 3 of emello, but don't want to use it any further. How do I opt out of allowing it to access my mail and to make changes to my trello cards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For Google account access**: If you want to disconnect your Google account from Emello, then:

1. Go to your accounts page (google.com/account)
2. Click `Security` in the left hand menu
3. Under "Connected applications and sites" click on `Manage access`

This will bring you to the tokens page where you can view and revoke access for any application that has been connected with your Google account. Find "Emello" and revoke its access.

**For Trello account access**: If you want to disconnect your Trello account from Emello, then:

1. Sign in to Trello then go to your Account Settings
2. At the bottom of the settings dashboard is a section called "Applications."
3. Revoke access to Emello from there.

Hope this helps!